# Stream Music from YouTube with Python

Tags: python, vlc, pafy

I'm looking to create a script that will pull a YouTube video url from a database and play it in a program using Python.

I currently have pafy and vlc setup and it works, but not exactly how I need it to.

```
import time, pafy, vlc, youtube_dl

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcCH6JpcK5w"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url

Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
duration = player.get_length() / 1000
player.play()
time.sleep(duration)
```

This *will* load the url and open up vlc player, which plays the video.

I would like to just be able to play the music without the vlc player. I was reading up on ffmpeg, but I'm not sure how/if it would work.

Any direction/insight would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass command line options to the vlc `Instance`.
So any option (I guess within reason) you can specify on the command line, can be passed into the `Instance` within python.

As there is a `--no-video` command line option, you can add that.
i.e.

```
Instance = vlc.Instance('--no-video ')
```

You can pass as many `options` as you like, just make sure they are space separated.